# glsl es dFdx/dFdy analog

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, glsles

I'm writing crossplatform application. It should run on Android devices.
I want to use dFdx/dFdy for antialiasing. But, unfortunately, glsl es 2.0 does not support derivatives.

Can I replace dFdx/dFdy with something? I.E. 1/sprite_width, 1/sprite_height in screen pixels.

As I said, I need this to work on android devices. And I saw that my device support GL_OES_standard_derivatives, which allow it to use this functions. Does all android opengl es 2.0 devices support it?

Comment: Amazon Fire TV Stick Gen1 does not support the GL_OES_standard_derivatives extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I said many Opengl ES 2.0 devices support GL_OES_standard_derivatives extension.
But for thoose who don't, I made this workaround:

```
float myFunc(vec2 p){
return p.x*p.x - p.y; // that's our function. We want derivative from it.
}


// this calculated in vertex shader
// width/height = triangle/quad width/height in px;
vec2 pixel_step = vec2(1/width, 1/height);       

float current = myFunc(texCoord);
float dfdx = myFunc(texCoord + pixel_step.x) - current;
float dfdy = myFunc(texCoord + pixel_step.y) - current;

float fwidth = abs(dx) + abs(dy);       // from khronos doc #http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_standard_derivatives.txt
```

P.S. I get very close results to the glsl built ins, A little bit more blurry (in my shader). To fix this I added multiply pixel_step  on  1/1.75. If someone knows why, let me know.

Comment: I also need something similar, specifically a fwidth() replacement.
Could you clarify your replacement?
Specifically where "dx" and "dy" variables come from.
Also the existing shader I have used the fwidth function with one parameter:

*float dist = texture2D(u_texture, vTexCoord).a;*
*float width = fwidth(dist);*

I am not sure how this ties in with your variable.fwidth. 
Thanks,

Comment: Well, in my case there was some quad with known size (and it was screen-space size, in my particular case). The derivative is function grow (in other words difference between current `f(x1)` and next `f(x2)` ). We have x1 (thats value that comes from vertex shader), the x2=x1+1/width. Than I calculate myFunc value at current pixel value (x1), and than calculate myFunc at next (x2). Then got the difference.

Comment: This is awesome! I used this in conjunction with Loop and Blinn's signed distance shader, I just needed to wrap your derivative up in a vec2 with the undifferentiated axis set to zero. Thanks a bunch!